# Terraform: Attaching pre-existing aws policies to a pre-existing aws role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, policy

Instead of using the aws console to simply attach a couple of pre-existing policies to a pre-existing role, I need to do it via Terraform within a module for a specific system that requires the perms.

I am not having much luck doing it though?

```
variables.tf
variable "masterrole" {
  description = "role already present within the cn-tio-tooling-acc"
  default = "arn:aws-cn:iam::12345678910:role/Master"
}
variable "policies" {
  description = "policies already present within the cn-tio-tooling-acc"
  default = "arn:aws-cn:iam::12345678910:policy/Source-1,arn:aws-cn:iam::351767606935:policy/Source-2"
}
```

data.tf  <-- Referencing the role and policy data that's already present within the account

```
data "aws_iam_role" "masterrole" {
  name = "Master"
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "policies" {
  arn = var.policies
}
```

IAM.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "Sources" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.masterrole.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policies.arn
}
```

Probably something really simple here, but why do I get the following from a 'plan' result?

***Error: Reference to undeclared resource
on cn_cpm_iam.tf line 3, in resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "Sources":
3:   role       = aws_iam_role.masterrole.name
A managed resource "aws_iam_role" "masterrole" has not been declared in the
root module.***

***Error: Reference to undeclared resource
on cn_cpm_iam.tf line 4, in resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "Sources":
4:   policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.cpmpolicies.arn
A managed resource "aws_iam_policy" "policies" has not been declared in the
root module.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When referencing data sources in terraform you need to prefix them with `data.`. So try using

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "Sources" {
  role       = data.aws_iam_role.masterrole.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.policies.arn
}
```

But as you already know the name and the ARN you can just use them without querying the data sources:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "Sources" {
  role       = "Master"
  policy_arn = var.policies
}
```

Let me know if i am missing something here ;)

Comment: mariux, You certainly haven't missed anything here. Great spot and your options fixed my 'plan' issues.  Thanks for helping out a relative newbie to terraform. :)

Comment: This is not a solution for the list of policies, looks like ```managed_policy_arns``` module should be used instead.

Comment: You are right, the answer concentrated on getting the error away and assumed the code is example code. The error fix is adding the `data.` prefix when referencing data sources. The assumption was the rest of the code is fine.

To make is usable as a list it just adding a `for_each` can solve it very easily. Not sure though what a "`managed_policy_arns` module" is. If you mean the attribute in the role resource it will take over full control and remove any other attachments.